# i linked the boostrap.css and boostrap.min.css but style is not working

Tags: html, css

I am tring to creating the Bootstrap Navbar, I linked the boostrap.css and boostrap.min.css successfully. but when i saw the browser it is not working in php.

```
 <link type="text/css" href="bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link type="text/css" href="bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Add css inside head tag and html inside body tag. Share your whole html file for better understanding of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss the head tag, thatswhy this can happen. Put your CSS links inside the head tag.

```
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" href="bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link type="text/css" href="bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>

  <body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
```

Comment: Hello @design kobi , thanks for accepting my answer. If it is useful for you then please upvote it so this is helpful for other programmers.

Answer (score 2):

are you sure that your css are loaded successfully? Check the console.. you have a relative path, use an absolute path to test if the problem vanish.

Here a fiddle with bootstrap included from cdn and your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sqmahtxz/

One more thing: you need to include only one css, the complete (for development) of minified version (for production).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably forgot to link the .js at the script tag? and you have to bind the links-tags in the header-tag.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And I suggest using this link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/ would be the introduction for bootstrap.

Comment: There is no need to load the JS for the CSS to work.